# How to have 'Pivot Row Totals' in server-side rendering ag-grid pivot mode

Tags: ag-grid

I use ag-grid enterprise edition and I would to add total columns in pivot mode. It is very clear in document how to do so but not in server-side rendering. The idea is that the back-end calculate the total of values for each row and I want to show it in the grid.

I tried a workaround using custom row groups and adding new columns to columnDef to describe the total columns, but it's not showing in the grid, because the total is not a row group. I can't find in the API a method to add a column that is not a Value column or a Pivot column in the ag-grid in pivot mode.

I want to know is someone find a way to do it in this context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I find how to do it. You just have to push the columns you want as total using gridColumnApi.setSecondaryColumns. It's important to be aware of the colId and field to match the key of your row data corresponding.